# Create Product using the json data

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, json

I have a task to create products programmatically using the JSON data.

I created a new module to make a custom controller. Then I hit the url using the http requester add on through Mozilla browser, and submitted the JSON data by POST method. But it does not fetch the submitted data.

If I am able to submit the JSON data through http requester to my controller, then I will be able to create the products using the same.

My controller code is updated here

```
<?php
class Probytes_Productcreate_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        

   public function indexAction() {
    $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response));
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getPost('test');
    echo $params;
    //die();
    }

}
?>
```

Is there any solution to sumbit a JSON data to the custom controller in magento. I am using magento version 1.9. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your code for posting JSON data

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: $params = $this->getRequest()->getPost('test'); put this as first line

Comment: not working! returns empty.

Comment: how can I submit a json data with a web request url

Comment: How you are posting data ? by form OR by curl OR another way  ?

Comment: "how can I submit a json data with a web request url" use curl to post data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37317/discussion-between-sibhi-s-and-minesh-patel).

Answer (score 1):

As Per discussion for http requester plug-in

Use Content Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and use content as your JSON Data

Comment: No need for the Content Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. As per your suggestion during the discussion $this->getRequest()->getRawBody() did the magic for me.